# iPhone: Memory Managment when cast between Objective-C objects and Core Foundation types

Tags: iphone

Whats going on when I use casting ? Should I release something when I use cast ? For example:

```
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)
    @"Helvetica", 16, NULL);
 CFRelease(font);
```

I have memory leak here..Why ? Should I release Helvetica CFStringRef ?

Another example:

```
 CTFramesetterRef frameSetter =
    CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(
    (CFAttributedStringRef)attrString);
 CFRelease(frameSetter);
```

Here I have memory leak too. Why ? How should I fix that ?

P.S. I DO NOT USE ARC

Comment: Does your code run on a separate thread? What does leak? CFStringRef?

Comment: no, code is on main thread. I'm using leak tool, and tool told me that at this line of code a have leak.

Comment: You shouldn't. Your first code part does not have a leak, unless your not running in a autorelease pool. @"Helvetica" is just a autoreleased NSString/CFString. 2nd code part could be a leak because i don't know, where attrString comes from and if it's autoreleased.

Comment: attrString is autoreleased..so there everything is fine. So if I do cast (CFStringRef)@"Helvetica" then everything is fine and i shouldn't care about object release ?

Comment: Yes. Looks all fine for me. A cast (normally) does not affect the memory. Did you try to analyze with Xcode's instruments? There you can exactly see what's leaking.

Comment: Nope, how to do that ? Run project as Analyze ?

Comment: No. Product->Profile. When instruments open, press use the memory leaks template. Analyze is just a static analyze and can not really dig into the running binary.

Comment: I found the problem, thanks for response....